# Wix installer UI not recognised in Fragment

Tags: user-interface, wix, 32bit-64bit, wizard

I have the following elements within the Product element

```
  <Fragment>
  <UI />
  <UIRef Id="WixUI_Mondo" />
  <!--<PropertyRef Id="WIX_IS_NETFRAMEWORK_461_OR_LATER_INSTALLED" />
      <Condition Message="This application requires .NET Framework 4.6.1 or later">Installed OR WIX_IS_NETFRAMEWORK_461_OR_LATER_INSTALLED</Condition>-->
  <Icon Id="DesktopIcon.exe" SourceFile="MyApplication.exe" />
```

I get the expected Wizard behaviour at install time.

If I move those elements under a Fragment instead, I get no Wizard at install time.
I'm creating both a 32 bit installer and a 64 bit installer. I'm looking to minimize duplicate configuration, hence the desire to put this in a Fragment (in a separate wix library project).

I made quite a few changes at the same time, which I thought were uncontroversial and also started running the installer from msiexec, so didn't notice the wizard disappeared immediately. I would have expected wix to report I had unreferenced ui elements if they have to be referenced from the Product element?

How's best to minimize the ui spec for a wix library shared with 32 bit/64 bit product projects?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is because of how `<Fragments>` are supposed to work. When you build your installer project you first do a pre-processing pass over the whole thing to build some object files. When building these object files if you have a reference to something in a fragment, that whole fragment is brought into the source. If there is no reference to something in the fragment that eventually ties back into the product for your msi, that fragment is discarded and removed from the object file.

What happened here is your UI is part of a collection of fragments in the WixUI wixlib which is embedded in the WixUIExtension dll. You can see the definition of the WixUI_Mondo [here](https://github.com/wixtoolset/wix3/blob/develop/src/ext/UIExtension/wixlib/WixUI_Mondo.wxs). You'll notice the whole thing is in a `<Fragment>` and if you drill down into the dialog wxs files that define the dialogs referenced they are also in fragments.

When you add `<UIRef Id="WixUI_Mondo" />` to your product you're telling the pre-processor to bring in all the referenced stuff into the main product's source.

What happened is you moved that UIRef out of your product and into a fragment. You have nothing tying that fragment into your main product now so it is just discarded during the build process and the final MSI doesn't have anything from the wixUI_Mondo in it.

If you want to put all the shared MSI XML into a fragment that is fine. You can 'tie in' that fragment to your main installer by using a `<xxxxRef>` element referencing the `<xxxx>` element in your fragment. A fairly simple way to do this is to just add a unused Property to your fragment defining what that fragment represents.

```
<Fragment>
  <Property Id="SharedInstaller" Hidden="true"/>

  <UIRef Id="WixUI_Mondo"/>
  <!-- lots of other shared installer stuff here -->
</Fragment>
```

And in your installer where you want to use this shared xml you can use

```
<Product Id="..." ... >
   <PropertyRef Id="SharedInstaller"/>

   <!-- more installer stuff unique to this version of the installer -->
</Product>
```

So when you build this project now, the pre-processor basically replaces the PropertyRef with **everything** in the fragment where that property is actually defined. If you already have a property or registrysearch in your fragment you can add a ref to that into your product.

You only need to reference one thing in a fragment to bring in the whole fragment. You can take some time looking through the wix source to see how they organize everything using extensive fragments. Packing everything tightly related into a fragment then building something bigger with all those fragments.

Comment: Wow- thanks Brian - a really comprehensive answer. I hadn't sussed that's how fragments work but it makes sense now you say it.

Comment: The documentation from FireGiant should be improved.  This one detail causes the whole custom UI to just disappear when I broke the large installer up into bite size chunks.